# Angular - content projection / passing async data to projected content

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

I have a Page HomePage which is holding a component called `InfiniteList`. Data is provided in the form of an `Observable[]` called `events$` to `HomePage` in ionViewDidLoad(). then the `events$` array is passed to the infinite-list like this:

```
<infinite-list [content]="events$ | async"></infinite-list>
```

In the infinite-list template i am using a different component to form the list:

```
<event-item *ngFor="let eventItem of content" [eventItem]="eventItem"></event-item>
```

Which is working perfectly. but i don't want to hardwire the `event-item` to the `infinite-list`, so that i can use the infinite-list component for different child components (e.g. event-item, event-item-small, or some other list). so i tried to use content projection:

```
<infinite-list [content]="events$ | async">
    <event-item *ngFor="let eventItem of content" [eventItem]="eventItem"></event-item>
</infinite-list>
```

i have added a `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag to the infinite-list component template, which is working as well. and i think i understand the concept of content projection. but the list of `<event-item>` is not being rendered, as `content` is somehow not available at the moment of rendering.

so i guess i can't say `let eventItems of content`. like i would if it was inside of the `infinite-list` component itself.

Comment: What you could do is set the exportAs property in the decorator of your component, then save the result in a template variable that you can iterate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

In your `infinite-list` component decorator, add an `exportAs` property.

Then in your template:

```
<infinite-list #component="valueOfExportAs" [content]="events$ | async">
    <event-item *ngFor="let eventItem of component.content" [eventItem]="eventItem"></event-item>
</infinite-list>
```

More information can be found here:

[Article about exportAs](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26)

An even better way can be seen in this article under 'Template references':

[ng-template, ng-container, ngTemplateOutlet](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Comment: thanks that worked. just for completeness: i had to use `"let eventItem of content.content"`. i have it like this now:

`<infinite-list #list="valueOfExportAs" [content]="events$ | async">
    <event-item *ngFor="let eventItem of list.content" [eventItem]="eventItem"></event-item>
</infinite-list>`

Comment: @malua I edited my answer to incorporate that. I also added a link to more advanced techniques which you can consider.